# Safari outline color

Tags: css, colors, safari, outline

I am trying to change the color of the outline when an element is active on Safari.

I need to keep all the styling of the default Safari outline, and just change the outline color.

I have tried:

```
a {

&:focus {
        outline: auto red;
      }
}
```

also

```
a {

&:focus {
        outline-color: red;
      }
}
```

when I do this

```
a {
&:focus {
  outline: red solid 2px;
}
}
```

the color of the outline will change but I loose all the other styling (rounded corners and the fade), I have tried different options with outline, outline-color, outline-style. Nothing seem to work.

Am I missing some basic behavior of Safari?

Thank you!

Comment: i prefer you using `border` rather then `outline` as `border` property support lot more then `outline`

Comment: I should explain that it is for keyboard users, and using a border moves the UI elements (when adding and removing the border).

Comment: There is a solution for that make border transparent by default and then on hover or active etc color that border(without effecting ui) its simple. If you need detail i can give you example of that.

Comment: Transparent borders will show as solid when in Windows high contrast mode.